# Delay of Display of JComponents inside JDialog?

Tags: java, swing

Whenever I make small changes to JComponents either in size or alignment, when tried to display

--> An empty dialog frame is displayed, when I try to enlarge the size of JDialog with the mouse the Components are Displayed...

-->So I disable the setResize() property...

-->still no effect...

Help me on this....

Thank You

Comment: are you modifying the components on the gui thread? (you should be)

Comment: @userNNNNN "Help me on this.... "  Please fix that sticky "." key and remember to ask a question.  Problems like this are commonly caused by failing to use layouts correctly.  If looking into the layouts does not sort the problem, I suggest you post an SSCCE (http://pscode.org/sscce.html) as my crystal ball is at the cleaners.

Comment: @Andrew Thompson: I can share my libastral source code :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing your code looks something like this:

```
dialog.pack();
dialog.setVisible( true );
dialog.add( someComponent );
```

The code should be:

```
dialog.add( someComponent );
dialog.pack();
dialog.setVisible( true );
```

That is you need to add the components to the dialog BEFORE you make it visible.

Comment: Yep!!!! That's the error.... I had earlier placed the pack() before initialization of JComponents... Thank You

Answer (score 1):

There are several things that can cause this:

Something's wrong with the layout managers you use: try calling `revalidate()` and `repaint()` on the content pane after you change your components. And make sure you make changes to all the components in the Swing Event Dispatch thread. You can do so by calling [SwingUtitlites.invokeLater()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingUtilities.html#invokeLater%28java.lang.Runnable%29).

If you're on a linux box with compiz on, java sometimes fails to redraw the frame. It's an old bug only partially fixed. Try to use metacity and see if you can reproduce the problem.

Comment: You should NOT be using doLayout(). If you add components to a visible GUI you can use revalidate() on the panel.

Comment: @user645757: can you reproduce the problem after calling `metacity --replace`?